# How to open a new instance of the same application?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'd like to open a new instance of the same application, much like chrome used to by default when opening a new tab [(See this)](http://cdn04.androidauthority.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Reenable-Chrome-tabs.png)

here's what I've tried so far:

```
PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
Intent launcher = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.package.name");
launcher.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
launcher.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
launcher.setData(Uri.parse(result.getExtra()));
getContext().startActivity(launcher);
```

it does start a new activity and also loads the correct data, but it doesn't open a new screen.

how would I achieve this?

**HERE'S MY MANIFEST FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.depa.browsing.stack">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http"  />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".About"/>
        <activity android:name=".Donate"/>
        <activity android:name=".Settings"/>
        <activity android:name=".GPL"/>
        <activity android:name=".History"/>

        <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "I'd like to open a new instance of the same application, much like chrome used to by default when opening a new tab" -- that is not opening a new instance of the same application. It is starting a new task, representing a new document. Try `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah that's not working either. plus, the parser says that FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT requires API 21+.  Maybe there's something missing in my manifest? I'll add it to the question.